# Reading integers separated by space in C++ using strtok

Tags: c++

I am trying to read various lines from the user using strtok but some kind of problem seems to be happenning and I can´t understand why the program doesn't even print the debug values I had.
Hope that some of you can help with it.

```
char* token;
char line[256];
int operations;
int time, depN;
vector<int> dep;

cin >> operations;
cout << "number operations " << operations << endl;

for(int i = 0; i< operations; i++){
   cin.getline(line,256);
   token = strtok(line, " ");
   cout << token << "--" << endl;
   time = stoi(token);
   while((token=strtok(nullptr, " ")) != nullptr){
      if(!flag){
         depN = stoi(token);
         cout << "DepN: " << depN << endl;
         flag = true;
      }else{
         dep.push_back(stoi(token));
      }
   }
   ...
   dep.clear();
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `strtok()` unless you're a 100% sure you have no other choice.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the token is space. You can use `stringstream`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < operations; i++) {
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(cin, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        if (ss >> time) {
            int token;
            while (ss >> token) {
                dep.push_back(token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what `flag` is for so I left that out.

Comment: I have done it using cin >> some_int for the number of ints I wanna read, but thank you for the answer! Ill keep stringstream in mind.

Comment: I think it depends on if you want to read line by line or want to just read a bunch of numbers. This approach is better if your data is line by line and you want to read a specific number of lines.

Comment: @drescherjm: Of course, if you just want to read a bunch of numbers, you can just read from `cin` to `time` and `token` directly. Just have to add a little error-handling to discard data when you hit garbage (or just treat it as an error and die). Both `cin` and a `std::stringstream` can be read from the same way. The OP's case seems to be mostly "just a bunch of numbers", so it could probably simplify to using `cin` directly, but line-oriented code works fine here.

Comment: Based on the use of `getline`, `strtok`, and `while` in the original code, I assumed the input was line based and the count was unknown. Ex: "1 2 3\n4 5 6 7".